# How can i iterate the values only once per row using map() or any JS function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a grid that will be displayed based on the row values from this.props
But for the column headings i am hard coding using the map function.

I have a requirement that based on the some value from this.props.[index of rows].x , particular column heading will not be displayed for each row

so here i created 2 variables that include column headings, if this.props.value[index of rows].x = true then i will be displaying titleA header value in else condition i will be displaying titlesB

```
    const titleA = [
      { titleA: messages.tableDetailsHeadPremiumLabel, size: 40 },
      { titleA: messages.tableDetailsHeadVolumeLabel, size: 20 },
      { titleA: messages.tableDetailsHeadInsuranceLabel, size: 10 },
      { titleA: messages.tableDetailsHeadNewPremiumLabel, size: 20 },
      { titleA: messages.tableDetailsHeadNewTotalLabel, size: 10 },
    ];

    const titleB = [
      { titleB: messages.tableDetailsHeadPremiumLabel, size: 40 },
      { titleB: messages.tableDetailsHeadInsuranceLabel, size: 10 },
      { titleB: messages.tableDetailsHeadNewPremiumLabel, size: 20 },
      { titleB: messages.tableDetailsHeadNewTotalLabel, size: 10 },
    ];


//logic where i conditionally displaying titlesA or titlesB
const headerColumns=
      this.props.members.map((val, i) => {
        if(val.x === true){

               return titleA.map((th, i) => {
               return <th key={i} style={{ width: `${th.size}%` }}><FormattedMessage {...th.titleA} /></th>;
             })}
          else if(val.show_volume_column === false){

            return titlesB.map((th, i) => {

              return <th key={i} style={{ width: `${th.size}%` }}><FormattedMessage {...th.titleB} /></th>;
            });
          }
//mapping rows from props
const rows = details.map((item, i) => {

      return <tr key={i}>
        <td>{item.a}</td>
        <td>{item.b}</td>
      </tr>
    })
//table
    return <Table className="details">
<thead>{headerColumns}</thead> //displaying the headerlogic
<tbody>{rows}</tbody>
</Table>
```

My issue is like for example: i have to map for each row since i need to display the heading for each , so if the rows are 10 , in that if we have 5 are true and 5are false , then the entire corresponding titleA and title B are displayed for each based on the count of boolean values, my aim is to display only title A if the particular row index has true else display the only titleB values if the particular row index has false

Is there any way where we can only display the titleA/titleB header values only once per the row.

Thank you

Comment: if it has to be used in a table view, I'd suggest using dataTables. https://datatables.net/